# How can I save the position of draggables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to jQuery and would like to know how I could save the location of the draggables in my code so that when the browser refreshes they stay in de same position. This is my code:

```
<style>

    #draggable1 { 
      width: 25px; 
      height: 25px; 
      margin-right: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      background-color: #19467c;
      border-radius: 3px;
      float: left;
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 15%;
    }

    #draggable2 { 
      width: 25px; 
      height: 25px; 
      margin-right: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;      
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      background-color: #19467c;
      border-radius: 3px;
      float: left;
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 15%;
    }

    #draggable3 { 
      width: 25px; 
      height: 25px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      background-color: #19467c;
      border-radius: 3px;
      cursor: grab;
      float: left;
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 15%;
    }

    #draggable4 { 
      width: 25px; 
      height: 25px; 
      margin-right: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      background-color: #19467c;
      border-radius: 3px;
      cursor: grab;
      float: left;
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 15%;
    }

    #draggable5 { 
      width: 25px; 
      height: 25px; 
      margin-right: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      background-color: #19467c;
      border-radius: 3px;
      cursor: grab;
      float: left;
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 15%;
    }

      #container{
          width: 35px;
      }

  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
            $( function() {
                $( "#draggable1" ).draggable();
              } );

            $( function() {
                $( "#draggable2" ).draggable();
              } );

            $( function() {
                $( "#draggable3" ).draggable();
              } );

            $( function() {
                $( "#draggable4" ).draggable();
              } );

            $( function() {
                $( "#draggable5" ).draggable();
              } );

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="draggable1" class="ui-widget-content">
          <p>1</p>
        </div>

         <div id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-content">
          <p>2</p>
        </div>

        <div id="draggable3" class="ui-widget-content">
          <p>3</p>
        </div>

        <div id="draggable4" class="ui-widget-content">
          <p>4</p>
        </div>

        <div id="draggable5" class="ui-widget-content">
          <p>5</p>
        </div> 

    </div>

<img src="motor.jpg" style="float;">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as this post suggests : https://forum.jquery.com/topic/save-position-of-draggable-item

You can actually save the position in a JSON file that you read each time you load your document, and update when mouse up is fired after a drag.

```js
var sPositions = localStorage.positions || "{}",
    positions = JSON.parse(sPositions);
$.each(positions, function (id, pos) {
    $("#" + id).css(pos)
})
$("#draggable3").draggable({
    containment: "#containment-wrapper",
    scroll: false,
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        positions[this.id] = ui.position
        localStorage.positions = JSON.stringify(positions)
    }
});
```

```css
  .draggable {
      width: 90px;
      height: 90px;
      padding: 0.5em;
      float: left;
      margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  }
  #draggable, #draggable2 {
      margin-bottom:20px;
  }
  #draggable {
      cursor: n-resize;
  }
  #draggable3 {
      cursor: move;
  }
  #containment-wrapper {
      width: 700px;
      height:500px;
      border:1px solid #000;
      padding: 5px;
  }
  h3 {
      clear: left;
  }
```

```html
<h3>TEST ME BELOW:</h3>

<div id="containment-wrapper">
    <div id="draggable3" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
        <p>DRAG ME</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hey Matt, this should be a comment to OP's post, or you need to give them a code solution. Don't just link to another answer.

Comment: I can't comment yet, as it requires 50 rep. But thanks ill edit this answer with the code.

Comment: No sweat, if you can't comment, you need to wait until you have enough rep to comment. You'll get rep by submitting good solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When I use this code the object isn't draggable anymore, any idea why? (did upvote you, but it won't show because of my rep ;-))

Comment: Hmm, i feel like it might be because of the IDs your are using. In the provided snippet of code, there is only one "draggable" div. And the id #draggable3 is used. So make sure you have  #draggable1,#draggable2,#draggable3,#draggable4,#draggable5 {
      cursor: move;
  }

Comment: If this answer worked for you please consider to mark as "Answer" for future reference.